# Android embedding with Firebase_core

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am an absolute newbie when it comes to Flutter development, but I'm learning! I've been plugging away at the same project file for almost 2 years now, so I'm sure some of the project files are a little outdated at this point. I'm trying to add Firebase integration to my app, but I'm getting this error:

"This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.
Take a look at the docs for migrating an app: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
The plugin `firebase_core` requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps on https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and re-run this command."

I did my best to follow the instructions in the links provided, but for the life of me I can't even figure past the first step. Google searches and forum searches have come up painfully blank for me.

Any help you could provide to update the Android embedding would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: Where are you actually stuck? Step 1A or 1B? Is 1B in your case actually needed? If not, just skip it. In worst case scenario, create new Flutter project and copy/paste your UI/UX in it and just use FlutterFire CLI to get up and running fast.

Comment: Trying to avoid copy/pasting, since I've got like dozens and dozens of custom widgets, pages, etc. I seem to be stuck at the very beginning - not sure if I need to do step 1a or 1b, but I can't even seem to find MainActivity.java to determine what I need to edit.

Comment: It says to look for android/app/src/main/java/[your/package/name]/MainActivity.java, but my project looks more like: android/app/src/main/java/io.

Comment: I'm on a Citrix environment, so can't open Android Studio now, but you should check out your filetree and it should be saying Project, not Android. Then go to android folder -> app -> src -> main -> java (or kotlin!) -> MainActivity.java (or .kt!)

Comment: Wait, is this an Ionic app? Then it might be here: /android/app/src/main/java/io/ionic/yourApp/MainActivity.java

Comment: within Android>app>srx>main>java all I see is an io folder, an AndroidManifest.xml file, and an ic_launcher-playstore.png file. Within the io folder, it goes io>flutter>plugins>GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java. No MainActivity.java (or .kt) file to be found...